# Airflow retries long running task multiple times while the task is still running

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-taskflow

I have a long running task where it loops through calling some REST endpoint to get data maybe hundreds of times and could take up to 1 hour.
While the task is still running, I see there are multiple attempts or retries, even though I specifically put `retries=0` on this PythonOperator that calls this particular function.
As part of the `default_args` I pass into the dag, it also has `"retries": 0`.

[image]

So I'm not sure what is retrying the task even while it is still running and no error whatsoever in the logs.

In the `airflow.cfg` file I have changed the following settings:

```
job_heartbeat_sec = 3600
scheduler_heartbeat_sec = 3600
scheduler_zombie_task_threshold = 3600
task_timeout=3600
```

But the symptom persists.

What else could be doing this?

The time between the retries as shown in the logs:

```
[2023-02-24, 02:32:12 UTC] {{taskinstance.py:1363}} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
```

```
[2023-02-24, 02:34:30 UTC] {{taskinstance.py:1363}} INFO - Starting attempt 2 of 1
```

```
[2023-02-24, 02:39:31 UTC] {{taskinstance.py:1363}} INFO - Starting attempt 3 of 1
```

The retry between attempts 2 and 3 (and sometimes if it retries more than 3 times, between 3 and 4, and 4 and 5...etc) is exactly 5 minutes.  I searched for "300" (seconds) in my airflow.cfg and only found `dag_dir_list_interval` is set to 300, which doesn't seem related.  Also, I'm not sure why the retry between 1 and 2 is some seemingly random length, 2 minutes and 18 seconds (i.e. not 5 minutes).

Comment: Were you able to figure out why this happens? Also did you use KubernetesPodOperator or the decorator method ?